# backslash doesn`t scape in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, backslash

I need to write a string to regex, but the backslash doesn`t scape.

```
let regex = "([A-Za-z0-9//:\\_\\-\\.])+\\1\\.png"
```

This will print:

```
([A-Za-z0-9//:\\_\\-\\.])+\\1\\.png
```

obs: I`m using Xcode 8 with Swift 3

Comment: @jtbandes, did you just edited in solution to the problem into question?

Comment: I just added monospace formatting to the code. But I agree it's unclear how it was supposed to appear. In the original version the "expected"/"actual" also looked exactly the same.

Comment: @jtbandes, i mean, did you replaced single backslash with double?

Comment: No. You can view the original, click on "source": http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40777112/revisions

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two backlashses `\\` because Swift have same style with C in String literals.

so your code should look like this

```
let regex = "([A-Za-z0-9//:\\_\\-\\.])+\\1\\.png"
```

Comment: Yes, but the two backlashes don`t result in one backlash

Comment: @ZaiaLorenz Could you give me one of a string example that you want to match with?